# Grouping to Periods Changes the Value

Tags: amcharts, amstock

If I set a max series of 100, and I have more data to display, amCharts is able to group my data and not show every single plot point. I like this. Except that when it groups them, my values change.

For example, in YTD, Sep 23, 2017 the value is 11.90 (correct). When I change the period to 1 yr or 3 yr, Sep 23, 2017 (where my data exceeds the max series), the displayed value changes to 12.36. Is there some sort of averaging going on here? How can I have amChart reflect the values that I provided for a specific date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default grouped value is the "Close" value, meaning the last value in the grouped period. This is configurable in the stockGraph object's [`periodValue`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#periodValue) property. You can configure it to other values such as:

- Open – the value of the first data point of a period
- Sum – the sum of all data points of a period
- Average – the average value of a period
- Low – the minimum value of a period
- High – the maximum value of a period

If you *don't* want the data grouping to occur, you can set [`maxSeries`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#maxSeries) to 0 in your categoryAxesSettings, which will make each point display its actual value rather than one of the grouped values. Note that this will affect the stock chart's performance as it uses the data grouping functionality to handle larger datasets.

This is all explained more in depth in AmCharts' [data grouping article](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/understanding-data-grouping-of-stock-chart/).